# Chance of losing a biased "Random Walk" game

Tags: probability, random-walk

Consider a game where you start with 1 point.

Then you flip a fair coin infinitely many times.

For each heads, you gain 2 points.
For each tails, you lose 1 point.

What is the probability that your score never goes below 1?

edit: I am looking specifically for the answer with flipping infinitely many times, not the probability after $N$ flips as $N$ approaches infinity.

Comment: On a cursory glance, I'd estimate its around 40%, but I'll give it a proper go later.

Comment: As a mode of attack:  Suppose you become "safe" if you reach $N$ points.  Then, this problem just has finitely many states with simple transition functions.  Now let $N$ tend to infinity.

Comment: In reference to your edit: the thing you are looking for, and the thing you say you're not looking for, are the same thing.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery This is not always the case, correct? Removable discontinuity can occur at infinity in formulas that may be conceived to solve this problem.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw I confess I'm not sure what you're talking about... the only reasonable way to define behavior at infinity in a setup anything like this is as a limit of finite behavior.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery: You can define probability distributions on the space of (countably) infinite sequences of coin flips.

Comment: @lulu: In order for that to work, one needs to first show the probability of winning the game in the OP is the limit of the probabilities of winning those truncated games.

Comment: ... the right line of attack, I think, is to first show that your score is unbounded with probability 1. Then you iteratively consider the games "Starting from score $n$, what are the odds you reach score $n+1$ without passing through score $0$?" To win the game in the OP, you have to win all of these games. (note that to say this, we are ignoring the bounded games, which is safe to do because that happens with probability zero)

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw to show that these are the same thing, let $X$ be the first time you reach $0$ if you do, and $X=\infty$ if you never do. Now $\Pr(X\neq\infty)=\Pr(X=1)+\Pr(X=2)+\cdots$, since these are the only possibilities and are disjoint. So $\Pr(X\neq\infty)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\Pr(X=i)$. But $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\Pr(X=i)$ is, by definition of an infinite sum, $\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^N\Pr(X=i)=\lim_{N\to\infty}\Pr(X\leq N)$, i.e. the limit of the probability of not having reached $0$ by time $N$.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime: I think that's not what the OP was referring to; rather the OP was referring to the answers received, which define $Y_N$ to be the event that you reach score $N$ before reaching score $0$, and then compute $\lim_{N \to \infty} P(Y_N)$.

Comment: @Hurkyl OP says "not the probability after $N$ flips".

Comment: @EspeciallyLime: I agree that's what the OP *said* -- I'm pointing out that context suggests that's not what the OP *means*. (mainly to give the OP a heads up to check if your response is actually in reply to his intent, but also in case you want to respond to what I think the intent is)

Comment: @Hurkyl "You can define probability distributions on the space of (countably) infinite sequences of coin clips." That's certainly true, of course, but what I was trying to claim is that almost any reasonable way of doing so that it is intended to model some iterated physical process should be realizable as a limit of finite sequence probability distributions.

Comment: @RushabhMehta Lost in the considerable discussion here: your guess was quite good!

Comment: @AaronMontgomery Thank you! I didn't have time to go back to this problem, but I'm glad my intuition wasn't too far off.

Answer (score 4):

One way to solve this is to let $p_n$ be the probability that, if you start with $n$ points, you eventually zero points. Observe that $p_1$ is also the probability that if you start with $n$ points, you ever have $n-1$ points.

Using this, one can see that $p_n=p_1p_{n-1}$, since the probability of getting from $n$ to zero equals the probability of eventually getting to $n-1$, then the probability of getting from there to $0$. In particular, we get that $p_n=p_1^n$ by using this argument.

Then, observe that $p_n=\frac{p_{n+2}+p_{n-1}}{2}$ by looking at what happens after the first step. Substituting in at $n=1$ gives $p_1=\frac{p_1^3+1}2$ gives that $p_1$ has to be either $1$ or $\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$. Clearly $p_1$ cannot be $\frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}2$ because that's negative. Thus $p_1$ is either $1$ or $\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}2$.

To see that $p_1$ is the lesser value, we can define $p_{n,t}$ to be the probability of reaching zero in at most $t$ steps. Note that $p_{n,t+1}=\frac{p_{n-1,t}+p_{n+2,t}}2$ and $p_{n,0}=0$ for $n>0$. Induction on $t$ using this formula quickly shows that $p_{n,t}\leq \left(\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}2\right)^n$ for all $n$ and $t$. Then, $p_n=\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}p_{n,t}\leq \left(\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}2\right)^n$ which implies $p_1=\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}2$

Finally, the probability you're interested in is $1-p_1$, which equals $\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}2$.

Comment: This is the best solution I think.

Comment: This solution is simpler than mine for this simple problem, but from experience I have found that arguments like mine are applicable in a broader variety of contexts. So it's worth examining both.

Comment: Actually, it now strikes me that there's a mistake in this argument.  $p_1$ is the probability of *losing* so we can't dismiss the possibility that $p_1=1$ out of hand.  Isn't that right?

Comment: @saulspatz Ah, you're right... I'll see if I can figure out an easy patch for that. (A nasty way to rule that out, in the same spirit as this answer, would be to let $f_n=\sum_i P(\text{reach zero first after i steps})\cdot x^i$, observe that $f_n=f_1f_{n-1}$ and $f_1=x\cdot \frac{f_1^3+1}2$, see that, as before, there are three solutions. You can use implicit differentiation at $x=1$ to find that $(1+f_1(1)^3)-2f_1'(1)+3f_1(1)^2f_1'(1)=0$ which, in particular, would imply that if $f_1(1)=p_1=1$, then $f_1'(1)=0$. This implies that the expected time until reaching $0$ was $0$ - contradiction)

Comment: @saulspatz I fixed the answer (with a better solution to the problem)

Comment: @MiloBrandt Yes, this is nice.  Thanks you.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the truncated problem, where you win once you get to at least $M$ points. This satisfies the recursion:

$$p_n=\frac{p_{n-1}+p_{n+2}}{2}$$

with the boundary conditions $p_0=0,p_M=p_{M+1}=1$. The general solution of this recursion is $c_1 r_1^n + c_2 r_2^n + c_3 r_3^n$ where $r_1,r_2,r_3$ are the roots of $x^3-2x+1=0$. One of these can be checked to be $1$; after finding that one, it is easy to compute the others as $\frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$. The boundary conditions imply

$$c_1+c_2+c_3=0 \\
c_1 + c_2 r_2^M + c_3 r_3^M = 1 \\
c_1 + c_2 r_2^{M+1} + c_3 r_3^{M+1} = 1.$$

This system can be solved for finite $M$ and then you can send $M \to \infty$ at the end. This is a bit laborious. If you want a shortcut, we can use some minor heuristics to get there. Set $c_3=0$ (since the only alternative is to have $c_1$ and/or $c_2$ grow without bound). Also assume that $c_2$ grows slower than $r_2^{-M}$, so that the $c_2$ terms in the second and third equations drop out.

Then the $M \to \infty$ equations read $c_3=0,c_1+c_2=0,c_1=1$, so $c_2=-1$. Thus with these heuristics, the general solution to your problem is $p_n=1-\left ( \frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2} \right )^n$, and the desired result in particular is $p_1=\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Strictly speaking, this is computing the probability that your score is never $0$ and goes to infinity. It is not totally obvious that the score has to go to infinity in order to play forever without losing. Indeed there are sequences of flips, such as $HTTHTTHTT\dots$, which never hit zero and do not go to infinity.

The reason that this works is that in any finite truncation of this type, the process terminates in finite time with probability $1$. (In other words, these "oscillatory" sequences collectively have probability zero). This can be viewed as a special case of a general result about irreducible Markov chains on a finite state space with an absorbing state: the absorption time is a.s. finite. Alternately, a shortcut for this particular problem is to note that no matter where you start, a run of at least $M/2$ successive heads will win you the game. So in an arbitrarily long (truncated) game in which you never lose you must eventually win. However you choose to see it, the only way to play forever without losing is to surpass all finite thresholds without losing, which is what was calculated above.

Comment: Surely, given a true uncountably infinite number of flips, the score not only goes below 1 at some point, but actually touches every possible score, infinitely many times each? It's essentially "Gambler's ruin" problem

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw There are problems such as the three-dimensional random walk where you do not necessarily reach every point as the steps tend to infinity. It is not obvious that you will touch every point.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw Uncountably infinite? The coins are necessarily in a sequence, hence countably infinite.

Comment: I can see this as the limit as $M\to\infty$ of the probability that you haven't lost after $M$ flips.  I don't see why it's the limit of getting arbitrarily large scores though.  I admit that this appears to give the right answer, but I'm uncomfortable with the argument.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery Sorry, in my mind this question was supposing infinite simulations of this infinite walk, if any of those simulations would eventually return at some point, which I put at 100% likelihood that at least one of those infinite simulations of the infinite walks would return at some point. Also since I was thinking of a set on infinite simulations of infinite walks I was thinking uncountably infinite steps. As opposed to a set of one simulation of an infinite walk, which has countably infinite sets.

Comment: @saulspatz: You are right to be uncomfortable, since this approach is computing the wrong thing! I'm pretty sure it turns out that the probability of winning the game described in the OP happens to be equal to the limit this answer computes, but that needs to be proven.

Comment: @Hurkyl The point is that in any "winnable" version of the game, you will win or lose in finite time with probability $1$. Thus to play forever, your trajectory must have won every winnable version of the game, which is exactly what I calculated.

Comment: @Ian Why do you say that you win in finite time?  Suppose you roll 
HTT HTT HTT ...
forever.  As I understand the question, you win.  At what *finite* time have you won?  Your score never get higher than $3.$  What does  this have to do with the score going to $\infty?$

Comment: @saulspatz The probability of that sequence is 0. But that's not useful, because the probability of *any* individual sequence is 0. So here's a stronger statement: fix any $N$. The *collective probability of all* paths that are permanently contained within the interval $[0, N]$ is 0.

Comment: @saulspatz With probability 1, you win or lose in finite time, given any threshold for victory. Nonetheless there are trajectories such as the one you described in which the game runs for an infinite amount of time, and these trajectories exist no matter how what victory threshold you set. But they collectively have probability zero.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery So, if I understand correctly, you are saying that a winning path almost surely has unbounded score.  If this is so, then I agree that Ian's calculation is correct.  I must say though that this seems like this statement should be included in the answer, along with at least an indication of the proof.

Comment: @saulspatz The proof I have in mind is technical but standard, using the usual machinery of recurrence/transience/etc. in Markov chains. I did point this out.

Comment: @saulspatz One argument for this: divide the time into intervals of the form $[1, N], [N+1, 2N], [2N+1, 3N], \dots$. If in any of those intervals all $N$ steps are to the right (or left), then the walk escapes the space-interval $[0, N]$. But that event has a positive probability, and the behavior of the walk on those disjoint time intervals is independent because it is a random walk. A positive-probability event given infinite chances to occur will do so almost surely.

Comment: @ Ian That sound reasonable, thanks.  I hadn't considered it in that light.  I need some time to think about it, but it's making sense to me now. 
 In my original solution which looks a lot like yours, I jumped to an unjustified conclusion, which happened to give the correct answer, and I think I've been having trouble getting it out of my mind.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery That seems convincing.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of tossing coins one by one, we can consider tossing coins in rounds. At the start of round 1 you have $1$ point. In each round, you toss as many coins as you had points at the start of that round. Note that this means you can never reach $0$ points part-way through a round, because the length of the round is the quickest you can reach zero. So the original problem is equivalent to determining whether you have $0$ points at the end of any round.

Now if you have $k$ points at the start of a round, your total points at the end of the round will be $k+\sum_{i=1}^kX_i$, where the $X_i$ are independent and take values $+2,-1$ with probability $1/2$ each. Equivalently, this is $\sum_{i=1}^kY_i$, where $Y_i=X_i+1$ are independent taking values $3,0$ with probability $1/2$ each. So this is a [Galton-Watson process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galton%E2%80%93Watson_process) with offspring distribution given by the $Y_i$. A standard result is that the extinction probability of such a process is the smallest positive root of $f(t)=t$, where $f(t)$ is the probability generating function of the offspring distribution.

Here $f(t)=(1+t^3)/2$, so the extinction probability is the smallest positive root of $t^3-2t+1=0$, which is $\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$. Thus the probability that your score never reaches $0$ is $1-\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}=\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach.  I calculated the probability of losing if you throw exactly $h$ heads, for $h=0,1,2,\dots$

[A001764](https://oeis.org/A001764) enumerates (among other things) the "Number of lattice paths of $n$ East steps and $2n$ North steps from $(0,0)$ to $(n,2n)$ and lying weakly below the line $y=2x.$" If we consider an East step as heads and a North step as tails, this is just the number of losing sequences $a_n$ with exactly $n$ heads, considering that we will toss one more tails at the end.

According to A001764, $$a_n={{3n\choose n}\over 2n+1}$$ and the probability of losing is $$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n2^{-3n-1}  $$

A July 17, 2108 comment on A001764 by Michael Somos says that $$A(1/8) = -1+\sqrt5$$ where $A(z)$ is the generating function of the $a_n$.  It's easy to see that $A(1/8)$ is the probability of losing, so that the probability of winning is $${3-\sqrt5\over2}$$

Alternatively, [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20binomial(3n,n)%2F(2n%2B1)2%5E(-3n-1)%20for%200%20to%20infinity&t=crmtb01) gives this value if one substitutes the explicit formula for $a_n$ into the sum.

I've been trying to find a simple derivation for the formula for $a_n$ based on Milo Brandt's elegant solution.  If the probability of heads is $p,$ then the same argument as Milo gave shows that the probability of losing is $$-\frac12+\frac{\sqrt{4p-3p^2}}{2p}\tag{1}$$  The series is $$(1-p)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_ny^n, \text{ where } y = p(1-p)^2$$

So far, I haven't been able to manipulate $(1)$ into a an expression in $y$ that will allow me to compute the $a_n.$

**NOTE**

I have removed the explanation of why I was dissatisfied with my original solution, which leave some of the comments without context.  My original solution was much like Ian's but my argument wasn't complete.  This points is discussed in the comments to Ian's solution, both by Ian and by Aaron Montgomery.

Comment: What is $a$ in your answer? Is it the starting position of the walk? If so, then yes, it is true that the win probability should go to $1$ as $a \to \infty$.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery No it was just an undetermined coefficient.  I set up a linear recurrence, solved the characteristic equation, and wrote down the general solution with undetermined coefficients $a,b,c.$  Then I argued that $b=0, c=-a$.  My $a,b,c$ were just the $c_1,c_2,c_3$ or Ian's solution.  I said $a=1$ simply because it seem to me that as your score increased without bound, your probability of winning must go to $1,$ but I later decided that this was just "proof by assertion."

Comment: Ah, got it. Yeah, the convincing argument thing you're hoping for is pretty hard, I think. It comes down to the classic kinds of issues: why is $\mathbb Z^2$ recurrent and $\mathbb Z^3$ transient, for example? I can produce a proof of that on the spot but I'm not sure that I have *intuition* for it. It is true that every transient MC has distant states: that is, if you pick an $x$, I can find a $y$ such that starting the chain at $y$ makes it arbitrarily unlikely for it to visit $x$. This chain is transient because it has a rightward drift. But how satisfactory is that explanation, really?

Comment: @AaronMontgomery I agree that the argument in terms of Markov chains is convincing.  I hadn't thought of it that way.  Still, once I get the solution in terms of the generating function completed, I have to say I'll find it more satisfying, because it's more concrete in some ill-defined sense.